# show items of an array in MessageBox

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, winforms

I'm having a problem printing out an array that I have created through a function.

All it says in the `MessageBox` is `System.int32[]`, what have I done wrong?

```
private int[] sekunder(int tid)
{
    int sekunder, minuter, timmar;
    sekunder = tid;
    minuter = sekunder / 60;
    timmar = minuter / 60;

    int[] beräknaTid = { sekunder, minuter, timmar };

    return beräknaTid;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int tid;
    tid = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(sekunder(tid)));
}
```

Comment: You are returning an array from the method sekunder. Try to show individual elements in Messagebox.Show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

Array Contains Multiple Elements You Need to Iterate through them

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int tid;
   tid = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

   foreach (var item in sekunder(tid))
   {
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(item));
   }
   // for comma separated 
   //use this : MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",",sekunder(tid)))
}
```

Comment: as yet another variant you can try `MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",",sekunder(tid)))`

Answer (score 1):

you can also join all values in your array and show them

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int tid;
    tid = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join(", ",sekunder(tid)));
}
```